# Julia: Can conditional statements evaluate code on the same line?

Tags: conditional-statements, julia

I am reading through the Julia manual right now and ran into my first potential disappointment.

I like being able to code conditional statements tersely.  In R I might write:

```
if (x==y) print("Hello")
```

In Julia however I think I might need do

```
if x==y
  println("Hello")
end
```

Or perhaps `x==y ? print("Hello") : print("")` which is certainly silly.

Is there some formulation in Julia for allowing for single line conditional statements?

Comment: You don't need the empty print. You could go for ``x==y ? print("Hello") : Nothing``, but @StefanKarpinski's short circuit ``&&`` operator is definitely prettier, and is considered the idiomatic way to do things like that in Julia.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can write `if x == y println("Hello") end` or, as has become somewhat idiomatic, you can use the short-circuiting behavior of the `&&` operator and write `x == y && println("Hello")`. In a very similar fashion it is fairly common to check some condition and throw an error if it isn't met by writing something like this: `size(A) == size(B) || error("size mismatch")`.

Comment: Though for the `if` statement case it is safer in general to add a semicolon between the condition and the body as in `if x == y; println("Hello") end`, the parser may interpret parts of the body as belonging to the condition otherwise.

Comment: I think `( x == y ) && println("Hello")` might also be safer and if there is assignment then `( x == y ) && ( z = 1 )` is definitely safer than `x == y && z = 1`.

Comment: @FrancisSmart the statement `x == y && z = 1` is not correct. It returns syntax error as it is not possible to assign values using Short-Circuit Evaluation